# Question on States and the GNS construction

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, c-star-algebras

I am trying to understand the proof of the GNS construction. I don't understand the follwoing step:
Let $\phi:A\to\mathbb{C}$ be a state, i.e. a positive ($\phi(a^*a)\geq 0$), linear functional. We consider the following set: $N_\phi=\{a\in A|\phi(a^*a)=0\}$. Then I want to show that this is a closed leftideal. Let $a\in N, b\in A$ then $\phi((ba)^*ba)=0$ is to show for left ideal.

I did read that we have $a^*a\leq ||a||^21$, but why is this true? I have the definition of the order $a\leq b$ if and only if $b-a$ is a positive element, i.e. of the form $b-a=c^*c$ for some $c\in A$.

Now if the above holds we have $a^*b^*ba\leq a^*||b||^2a=||b||^2a^*a$, since $b\mapsto a^*ba$ preserves positivity.

But then why does $\phi$ preserve $\leq$, i.e. why does $\phi(a^*b^*ba)\leq \phi(a^*||b||^2a)$ hold?

I would like to avoid the consequence $a\leq b \Rightarrow ||a||\leq||b||$, since I want to show this, using the GNS construction. However if someone can tell me how to prove this implication without GNS then I could use it.

Comment: You can prove all inequalities you want via functional calculus. For example, $f\le \|f\|1$ for $f\in C(X)$ where $X$ is compact Hausdorff so by functional calculus this holds in any unital commutative C*-algebra. The result for arbitrary unital C*-algebras then follows by considering the C*-algebra generated by the appropriate element.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My problem with your argument or other similar arguments like that are that I have problems with the abstract definition of $leq$ in an abstract $C^*$-algebra and the naive notion of $\leq$. However I now found a proof myself, should I rather edit my question, answer it by myself or just delete it? (Funny I was thinking of it the whole day and 30minutes after posting the question I was able to prove it)

Comment: @Roland I think that since it is an elementary question that is covered by other material here, it's okay to delete it. You can still answer it yourself if you want to, it's really up to you!